# special characters in Json feed getting inserted as unknown characters in sqllite database

Tags: android, json, utf-8, inputstream, httpconnection

In my Android app, Json feed may have special characters of French, German and Spanish language like "Atlético Madrid vs Málaga". Feed works fine when i see them in browser but sqllite shows unknown characters when the same data is being inserted. On the recommendations by experts on StackOverFlow in other posts, I made these changes in HttpConnections as well as in InputStream to support UTF-8 but it's not working. I was told that sqllite supports UTF-8 on its own and no config changes are required. What's wrong i am doing ? Please help. Thanks.

```
    InputStream isC = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        isC = conn.getInputStream();
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(isC, "UTF-8"));
        jsonReader.setLenient(true);
        jsonReader.beginObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

you're decoding as UTF-8, which supports ASCII charachers only.

If a non-ascii character (á, ó, ú, í, é) is encountered, you'll get weird behaviour.

also, make sure the column you're saving to in the database supports Unicode - in MsSql, it'd need to be a nvarchar field. Not sure what the SQLite equivalent is...